# Cantelli's and Chebychev

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In The proof of Chebychev's inequality and of Cantellli's inequality I came across  the following:

1) $P(\lvert X - E[X]\rvert \ge a) = P((X-E[X])^2 \ge a^2)$

Could I get an explanation of this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common "trick." In fact if $f$ is any strictly increasing positive function (i.e. invertible), then $P(|X-E[X]|\geq a)=P(f(|X-E[X])\geq f(a))$. To see this, just work with the set defintions: $A=\{\omega: |X(\omega)-E[X]|\geq a\}=\{\omega: f(|X(\omega)-E[X]|)\geq f(a)\}$, so that the probabilities must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lvert X - E[X]\rvert \ge a$ occurs for exactly the same values of $X$ for which  $(X-E[X])^2 \ge a^2$ occurs, the events have the same probability.

(In fact, they are the same event.  If you know measure theory, and you view $X$ as a function $\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$, then each inequality is satisfied by the same subset of $\Omega$.)